# Cannot access deleted builds using the TFS 2015 REST API

Tags: rest, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Using the older TFS API, it's possible to access deleted builds using the following code:

```
IBuildDetailSpec buildDetailSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(m_teamProject, m_buildDefinition);
buildDetailSpec.BuildNumber = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_buildPrefixOverride))? m_buildDefinition + "*" : m_buildPrefixOverride + "*";  
buildDetailSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = m_maxBuildPerDefinition;
buildDetailSpec.Status = BuildStatus.All;
buildDetailSpec.QueryDeletedOption = QueryDeletedOption.IncludeDeleted;
buildDetailSpec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.StartTimeDescending;
buildDetailSpec.InformationTypes = null;
IBuildQueryResult buildQueryResult = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDetailSpec);
```

On the other hand, it seems impossible to query that same thing using the TFS 2015 Update 2 (on-premise) REST API according to the documentation.

This is the query I'm running:

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/BuildTools/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&definitions=1227
```

Did anyone manage to query them? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

[REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/builds#GetalistofbuildsForabuilddefinition) doesn't include query deleted option like .Net API [IBuildDetailSpec.QueryDeletedOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetailspec.querydeletedoption(v=vs.120).aspx).

When get a list of builds for a build definition, REST API below only output the builds not deleted:

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/BuildTools/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&definitions=xx
```

You may consider submit a user voice at website below: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I have posted a User Voice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13833075-add-deleted-builds-option-in-the-builds-rest-api-q